# what is more efficient in a M:N relationship: delete+insert or update

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a M:N relationship.

```
-----------
|     M   |
-----------
| id(PK)  |
-----------

-----------
|    N    |
-----------
| id(PK)  |
-----------

-----------------
|       MN      |
-----------------
| Mid, NId (PK) |
-----------------
```

M:N normalized relationship.

On update, I'll send to the backend [(Mi, Nj), (Mk, Nm), ...].

I need to remove all missing pairs and add any new pair.

what is more efficient:

1. Remove all MN pairs and reinsert them
2. Get all MN pairs and compare them, find any missing pairs and any new pairs. Delete missing pairs and insert any new pairs.

Any other solution is welcome! :D

I am using postgres.

Comment: Hint: try to estimate the number of changes for the (Mid,Nid) PK in both cases.

Comment: clearly, compare and update only when it's needed it's more efficient. but I can force situations when perhaps this type of approach it isn't as good as it seems at first. I was wondering about them and other kinds of problems related with postgres's insert and update implementation (I don't know much about PG). maybe my question was a bit too plain.

Comment: `Delete missing pairs and ...` If the pair is a pair of FKs (which it should be)  there **cannot be** any such pairs (FK pointing to nothing), and since they form a PK, they cannot (should not) be NULL either. BTW: in Postgres, a PK *implies* the presence of a unique index.

Comment: imagine the following: M1, M2, M3 and N1, N2 items. My user has the following relationships: (M1, N2) and (M2, N2). He/she updates the relationships to (M1, N2) and (M1, N1). I need to remove (M2,N2) and add (M1, N2). there is no NULL.